# Function that deletes a specific node of a singly linked list (c)

Tags: c, list

I'm trying to create a function that deletes a node that contains a specific value from a singly linked list. The code works fine if the value doesn't happen to be at the last node of the list but when it's on the last node an error pops up:

0

1

```
free(): double free detected in tcache 2
Aborted (core dumped)
```

--Here's the code:

```
node *delete(node* head, int value)
{
    node *pr = head;
    for (node *cur = head; cur != NULL; cur = cur->next)
    {
        if (cur->val == value)
        {
            if (cur->next != NULL) pr->next = cur->next;
            else pr->next = NULL;
            free(cur);
            return head;
        }
        else pr = cur;
    }
    return head;
}
```

Comment: You should get trouble for deleting the *first* node (i.e. when `cur == head` in the loop) in the list.

Comment: Please show a [mcve]

Answer (score 1):

If the node you want to delete is the first node in the list (which is the case when there's only a single node in the list) then `cur` will be the same as `head`.

That means when you call `free(cur)` that's also equivalent to `free(head)`.

Then you do

```
return head;
```

But that pointer is invalid and can't be used. Any attempt to use the returned pointer will lead to *undefined behavior* and likely crashes.

You need to add a special case when the node to be deleted is the head node. Perhaps something like this:

```
if (head && head->val == value)
{
    // Non-null head, and it's the node to delete

    // Need to save the next pointer, as we can't dereference head after we free that node
    node *next = head->next;

    // Free the node
    free(head);

    // And return a pointer to the next node (might be null)
    return next;
}
```

Of course, that requires you to always assign the returned pointer to `head` when you call the function:

```
head = delete(head, value);
```